# Examine if function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ which is defined as $f(x,y)=(2x-y,x-4y)$ is bijective. If bijective, find $f^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Function is bijective when it is injective and surjective. Function is injective if $$(\forall x_1,x_2 \in A)f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$$ and surjective if $$(\forall y \in B)(\exists x \in A)y=f(x)$$
Is it possible to transform a function, so that it is given in explicit form? I don't know how to manipulate with function in this form ($f(x,y)=(2x-y,x-4y)$).

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Try to solve $(z,w)=(2x-y,x-4y)$ for $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matrices.
your function $f$ can be written as

$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{rl}
2& -1 \\
1 & -4
\end{array}\right).
$$
Here $f(x,y)=A\binom{x}{y}$.

By finding $A^{-1}$ you can describe $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Surjectivity: take a target $(a,b)$

Tou have $2x-y=a$ and $x-4y=b$, which is a system that solves like that:

$x=\dfrac{4a-b}{7}$ and $y=\dfrac{a-2b}{7}$. Thus every target can be reached, and $f$ is surjective.

Injectivity is kind of easier even.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$(z_{1},z_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Then some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that
$z_{1} = 2x-y$
and
$z_{2} = x-4y$
if and only if
$$
x = \frac{4z_{1}- z_{2}}{7},
y = \frac{z_{1} - 2z_{2}}{7},
$$
so $f$
is bijective and 
$$f^{-1}: (z_{1},z_{2}) \mapsto \bigg( \frac{4z_{1}- z_{2}}{7}, \frac{z_{1} - 2z_{2}}{7} \bigg)$$
on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: Is it possible to find $f^{-1}$ explicitly, without using matrices?

Comment: Sorry? I did not use any matrix theory. What I showed is that for every $(z_{1},z_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ there is exactly one $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $f(x,y) = (z_{1},z_{2})$, so the bijectivity follows. But that also gives the inverse function $f^{-1}$.